# When a controller class shouldn't has the [ApiController] attribute?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm learning asp.net core to create a rest API and the docs at msdn suggests (from my interpretation of the text) that you could have a controller class (ie. a class that inherits from `ControllerBase` or `Controller`) that could not have the `[ApiController]` attribute.

Is that right? If so in what circumstances a controller don't need the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

ApiController provides some specific functions, you don't need to use these or not add it, it depends on your own needs.

The [ApiController] attribute can be applied to a controller class to enable the following opinionated, API-specific behaviors:

1.[Attribute routing requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-requirement)

2.[Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses)

3.[Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference)

4.[Multipart/form-data request inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#multipartform-data-request-inference)

These features require a compatibility version of 2.1 or later.